# What is the use of -pre in Chocolatey?

Tags: chocolatey

I see a lot of instructions when using Chocolatey to install and then `-pre` at the end. What does that command do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means install newest version, including any pre-release that may be available.

From https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsInstall:

```
 --pre, --prerelease
 Prerelease - Include Prereleases? Defaults to false.
```

Comment: Also at https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install